# get always null when using IFormFile and [frombody] object in asp.net core 2 and swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, swagger

i get null when i  add [frombody] attribute , before i add it its work correctly but i want to get my object from body, i use asp.net core and swagger

its my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("add-content")]
public async Task AddConten(IFormFile uploadedFile,[FromBody]ContentDTO content)
{
    var fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + "-" + uploadedFile.FileName;
    var path = (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"UplodedFiles\ContentFiles\"+fileName);

    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await uploadedFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }
}
```

its My Filter:

```
public class FileUploadOperation :IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {         
        if (operation.OperationId  == "ApiCpAdd-users-by-filePost" ||
            operation.OperationId == "ApiPortalAdd-contentPost")
        {
            operation.Parameters.RemoveAt(0);
            operation.Parameters.Add(new NonBodyParameter
            {
                Name = "uploadedFile",
                In = "formData",
                Description = "Upload File",
                Required = true,
                Type = "file"
            });
            operation.Consumes.Add("multipart/form-data");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make your `IFormFile uploadedFile` a property of the `ContentDTO` model (and delete the parameter from the method)

Comment: i used a customized filter, if i encapsulate IformFile in ContentDTO, i cant  get expected result  in swagger